# How to disable Golang unused import error

Tags: go

By default, Go treats unused import as error, forcing you to delete the import.
I want to know if there exists some hope to change to this behavior, e.g. reducing it to warning.

I find this problem extremely annoying, preventing me from enjoying coding in Go.

For example, I was testing some code, disabling a segment/function. Some functions from a lib is no longer used (e.g. fmt, errors, whatever), but I will need to re-enable the function after a little testing. Now the program won't compile unless I remove those imports, and a few minutes later I need to re-import the lib.

I was doing this process again and again when developing a GAE program.

Comment: It is not a good idea to leave unused imports in your code, but you can just comment them out temporarily.

Comment: I agree it is not a good idea to leave unused imports but it a bad idea to unnecessarily waste programmer's effort to do things like this especially this is occurring very often when testing something out. Those down vote must be for my attitude to GO by those Go fans.

Comment: It's a feature, [not a bug](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3778&can=1&q=unused%20imports&colspec=ID%20Status%20Stars%20Priority%20Owner%20Reporter%20Summary).

Comment: Removing unused imports is a good thing. There are many style guides that require all warnings to be treated as errors, so adding a new warning is generally a bad idea. Perhaps a -dev flag might be a possible compromise, but the `var _ = <module>.Function` works fine and it's conspicuous enough to prevent it from being a common practice.

Comment: As someone is touching on in the answers below, I recommend either using an IDE that manages imports (Gogland, LiteIDE, etc. -- there are several), or have `goimports` as a step in your build process. Without either of those it gets old really fast.

Comment: Honestly, just use `goimports` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838243/2422529). Configure your editor to fix imports on save and be done with this nightmare.

Comment: Some libraries may be necessary during debugging only, and it is very annoying if your linter removes them while you save your source code.

Answer (score 53):

Adding an underscore (`_`) before a package name will ignore the unused import error.

Here is an example of how you could use it:

```
import (
    "log"
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)
```

> To import a package solely for its side-effects (initialization), use
>   the blank identifier as explicit package name.

View more at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations

Comment: This is the correct answer. Based on the GoLang specification Doc, it is intended to be used to import a package solely for side-effects (initialization). GoLang Spec Doc here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations

Comment: Simply fantastic.  This should be in a list of top ten things devs new to golang should know.  Thank you!

Comment: Not very useful. The problem with this is that if you later want to use the import again you must remove the `_` (otherwise the package cannot be referenced, as it has no name). If you're going to do that you might as well just comment/uncomment it. The `var _ = ...` trick doesn't have this problem.

Comment: If you add the underscore to `"fmt"` in Gogland, it automatically adds `"fmt"` so that you have both `_"fmt"` and `"fmt"`, which renders it useless in this IDE

Comment: In what way is any of this an improvement over simply commenting out the respective imports?

Answer (score 32):

The `var _ = fmt.Printf` trick is helpful here.

Comment: I love this solution. It's ugly enough to make it undesirable, but it works so it's there if you really need it.

Comment: For more details please check this link http://tip.golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_unused

Comment: It's helpful in the moment, but when I used this technique I tended to not go back and delete the unused blank identifier later, causing imports to stick around when I really didn't intend to use them in the long run. Using a tool like goimports has solved the real problem and ensures that my imports are always minimal and clean.

Comment: Still a stupid hack in my opinion, though probably the most efficient thing to do.

Comment: +1 because this can be done **anywhere in the file**, which would normally be an awful idea but is really useful for saving you from having to jump around the file to get to the `import` statement and back when you're just trying to compile or test some code file that you are *iteratively* fleshing out.

Answer (score 30):

I have the same problem. I understand the reasoning for why they implemented the language to disallow unused imports and variables, but I personally find this feature annoying when writing my code. To get around this, I changed around my compiler to allow optional flags for allowing unused variables and imports in my code.

If you are interested, you can see this at https://github.com/dtnewman/modified_golang_compiler.

Now, I can simply run code with a command such as **go run -gcflags '-unused_pkgs' test.go** and it will not throw these "unused import" errors. If I leave out these flags, then it returns to the default of not allowing unused imports.

Doing this only required a few simple changes. Go purists will probably not be happy with these changes since there is good reason to not allow unused variables/imports, but I personally agree with you that this issue makes it much less enjoyable to code in Go which is why I made these changes to my compiler.

Comment: I have also done the same with the 1.6 release, check here if interested: https://github.com/ronelliott/go/tree/release-branch.go1.6 NOTE: some tests will fail

Comment: I love the idea behind this. I see that you're fork is still at version 1.2 though, which makes it useless. This should be included in the standard go compiler, at the least so that `go run main.go` disables the errors by default, while `go build` enables the errors. That way it's easy to develop using `go run` and when it's time to build for production, you are still forced to clean up your code.

Comment: For a go 1.16.2 fork that allows unused imports by default, try this: https://github.com/kindlychung/go

Comment: Same here: Deactivating import checks can be necessary if you want to measure performance in runtime during debugging. Every modern IDE allows you to evaluate expressions in runtime during debugging. You don't necessarily need the imports necessary for this purpose in your standard code; maybe you don't use them at all. But you don't need them automatically removed by a linter either, what does, what it wants. :/

Answer (score 21):

Use [goimports](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports). It's basically a fork of `gofmt`, written by Brad Fitzpatrick and now included in the go tools packages. You can configure your editor to run it whenever you save a file. You'll never have to worry about this problem again.

Comment: This is objectively the correct answer.

1. Use go imports
2. configure your editor to format on save
3. Be done with this nightmare for good.

Comment: In the online documentation: Command `goimports` updates your Go import lines, adding missing ones and removing `unreferenced` ones. That is not really helpful. What to do if I only need an import during debugging and for debugging purposes only?

Answer (score 7):

Use `if false { ... }` to *comment out* some code. The code inside the braces must be syntactically correct, but can be nonsense code otherwise.

Comment: More than syntactically correct, any referenced variables (e.g. foo.Bar) must exist, etc.

Comment: This is not very clean or idiomatic. There is a reason why Go was designed the way it was

Comment: This is a nice technique when one is simply trying things out while developing a script or exploring APIs in Golang.  Thank you topskip!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `fmt` package for general printing to console while you develop and test then you may find a better solution in the [log](http://golang.org/pkg/log/) package.

Comment: Or the builtin function `println` which people always seem to forget about.

Comment: @MatrixFrog In the long run, it is not a good idea to build upon these functions as they may vanish over time. Using log is a good idea as you might keep these and it is part of the standard library and unlikely to be removed. See [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Bootstrapping) for details.

Comment: Builtin `println`?? This is news to me. Is it undocumented? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @nemo good point. They're perfect for when you need to print something out as a quick one-off, but you don't intend to actually check it in. Probably not good to use them in any other case.

Comment: I think the problem is not fmt vs log, it's the fact that if you disable logging (whether that be fmt or log), Go refuses to compile as now you have an unused import.

Comment: @MatrixFrog `These functions are documented for completeness but are not guaranteed to stay in the language.`

Comment: This doesn't answer the asked question, but is a comment.

Comment: @MartinTournoij - I disagree. This was the solution I eventually found when I had this issue 5 years ago and with 5+ upvotes it has clearly helped others. I was a newbie using the `fmt` package for logging, unaware that there was a ready-made logging package.

Comment: But that is not what the question is asking about; it's asking about disabling this error in general, not just about how to more effectively print debug statements.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people have already commented with valid justification and I also acknowledge the original author's intention. However, Rob Pike mentioned in different forums that Go is the outcome of simplification of the processes that a few other mainstream programming languages either lack or not easy to achieve. It's Go's language semantics as well as to make the compilation faster, there are a lot of things that are adopted which initially seems inefficient.

To make it short, unused imports are considered as errors in Go as it blots the program and slows down the compilation. Using import for side effect (_) is a workaround, however, I find this confusing at times when there is a mix of valid imports with side effects along with side effects imported purely for the purpose of debugging/testing especially when the code base is large and there is a chance to forget and not delete unintentionally which may confuse other engineers/reviewers later. I used to comment out the unused ones, however, popular IDEs such as VS code and Goland can use `goimports` easily which does the insertion and deletion of the imports pretty well. Please refer to the link for more info, https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_import

Comment: Thanks for this! I'd suggest explicitly copy-pasting the line of code from the URL you posted into your response as a concrete example of importing for side-effect:

`import _ "net/http/pprof"`

Comment: Thanks @Dragon for your suggestion! Since I am a new contributor, with the help of people like you, I will get better with my posts quickly.

Comment: Deactivating import checks can be necessary if you want to measure performance in runtime during debugging. Every modern IDE allows you to evaluate expressions in runtime during debugging. You don't necessarily need the imports necessary for this purpose in your standard code; maybe you don't use them at all.  But you don't need them automatically removed by a linter either, what does, what it wants. :/

Comment: We have the same initial problems with every new programming language. All of them believed at the time of the creation of their excellent language that wisdom is eaten with spoons. The opposite is the case. I don't care what the creators thought. I want to be able to override any rule intentionally. The linters must also be Turing-complete. There should be a configuration file for that, maybe placed at the root of your project, so that everyone can look at it and see what is deactivated and why.

Answer (score 1):

put this on top of your document and forget about unused imports:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

var _, _, _, _ = fmt.Println, bufio.NewReader, os.Open, filepath.IsAbs
```

Comment: Instead of making the compiler generate dead code *if* you really wanted to do this, use `_` global variables instead (e.g. either one package per line or if you insist, all together like: `var _, _, _, _ = fmt.Println, bufio.NewReader, os.Open, filepath.IsAbs`). But don't do this, just use `goimports`.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a new Golang compiler, which will simply ignore all `variable unused warning` and `import unused warning` and `function unused warning` by default.

https://github.com/yingshaoxo/go/releases/tag/v1.21

It works for both `go run` and `go build`